# Limit of sequence with multiplication

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{(a-1)^2} \right) \left( 1- \frac{1}{(a-2)^2} \right)... \left( 1- \frac{1}{(a-n)^2} \right) $$

$$ a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{N} $$
How do i go about calculating limit in such product?

Comment: Try to $\ln$ it.

Comment: Is $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}^+$?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty important forgot to add that $$ a \in C , a \notin  N $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{(a-2)^2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}\right)=\frac{(a-3) a}{(a-2) (a-1)}$$

They kind of "telescope" like in series

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{(a-2)^2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{(a-3)^2}\right)=\frac{(a-4) a}{(a-3) (a-1)}$$

And finally 
$$\prod _{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{(a-k)^2}\right)=\frac{a (a-n-1)}{(a-1) (a-n)}$$
I don't want to offend you and do the last move to get the limit, but you promise not to be offended I can add
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{a (a-n-1)}{(a-1) (a-n)}=\frac{a}{a-1}$$

Hope this is useful